# Load wrong image in ListView using Universal Image Loader Android?

Tags: android, image, listview, android-listview, universal-image-loader

I have a list contains: contentString and list images, it look like:

```
[{
"contentString": "Image",
"images": [{
    "image": "url"
}]
}, {...}]
```

Then I try loading it in `ListView`.

My holder:

```
class Holder {
    TextView Content;
    ImageView ImageButton;
    ImageLoader imageLoaderPost;
    public Holder(TextView Content, ImageView ImageButton, ImageLoader imageLoader) {            
        this.Content = Content;
        this.ImageButton = ImageButton;
        this.imageLoaderPost = imageLoader;
    }

}
```

Load View in ListView:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View v = convertView;

final Holder holder;
if (v == null) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_row, parent, false);
    TextView Content = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ContentTextView);
    ImageView ImageButton = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ImageButton);
    ImageLoader imageLoaderPost = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    holder = new Holder(Content, ImageButton, imageLoaderPost);
    v.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (Holder) v.getTag();
}

final HTPost post = postList.get(position);

// post content
holder.postContent.setText(post.getContentString());

//
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2)
    .considerExifParams(true)
    .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
    .cacheOnDisk(true)
    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
    .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
    .build();
// image
if (post.getImages().size() > 0) {

    holder.imageLoaderPost.displayImage(post.getImages().get(0).getImage(), holder.postImageButton, options, new ImageLoadingListener() {@Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String s, View view) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String s, View view, FailReason failReason) {}

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String s, View view, Bitmap bitmap) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String s, View view) {}
    });
} else {
    //holder.imageLoaderPost.cancelDisplayTask(holder.postImageButton);
    log("Wrong image: " + post.getContentString());
}
return v;
}
```

With rows don't have image, I only load contentString and print: `log("Wrong image: " + post.getContentString());`

But in `ListView`, I see a image be loaded with Content. (Row without image but have image in `ListView`, Image coincides with 1 in all images be loaded before).

I don't know why, maybe cache of `ImageLoader`?
Any helps, thanks!

Comment: Try downloading images into listview using volley library its very easy. You can easily get example frok androidhive

Comment: I used ImageLoader many place, and it waste time to changes all. May I fix it by ImageLoader?

Comment: cache the images then it will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [ViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder) so the row in `ListView` will be reused without recreate repeatedly. 
Therefore, you will have the image in all rows.

The simple solution is hide `ImageView` in the rows where you don't want it

```
    if(your condition){
        ...
        holder.ImageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ... load your image
        ...
    } else {
        log("Wrong image: " + post.getContentString());

        holder.ImageButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  //hide your ImageView or you can load default image
    }
```

Hope this help

Comment: I don't think this cause is My Holder due to I catch this issue before I used holder. Anyway, I used holder.ImageButton.setVisibility(View.GONE); and look like it not working, ImageButton will lost.

Comment: if you hide the image, did you visible it when you want to load image

Comment: I have modify my answer, please try it

Comment: Great, I did it. I'm just think about cache without remember it. Thank!

Answer (score 0):

To load image from server asynchronously you can use Picasso small library.It is just one line code. Here is `gradle`

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.3'
```

here is your ImageView

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Here is the simple java code

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    Picasso.with(this)
            .load("YOUR_IMAGE_URL")
            .into(imageView);
```

That's it. For more information , visit [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-working-with-picasso--cms-22149)